# Safe element of array access

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, tryparse

What is the safe method to access an array element, without throwing `IndexOutOfRangeException`, something like `TryParse`, `TryRead`, using extension methods or LINQ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the following extension method.

```
public static bool TryGetElement<T>(this T[] array, int index, out T element) {
  if ( index < array.Length ) {
    element = array[index];
    return true;
  }
  element = default(T);
  return false;
}
```

Example:

```
int[] array = GetSomeArray();
int value;
if ( array.TryGetElement(5, out value) ) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: You should change array[i] to array[index]. Also, I think your logic is backwards. If array.Length <= index, then trying to access array[index] is going to throw an exception.

Comment: @Jim, that's what I get for posting before I had my coffee finished.  Fixed the typos

Comment: Might also want to check that index >= 0.

Answer (score 60):

Use the `System.Linq` [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault) method. It handles an out-of-range access without throwing an exception.
It returns a default value in the case of an invalid index.

```cs
int[] array = { 4, 5, 6 };
int a = array.ElementAtOrDefault(0);    // output: 4
int b = array.ElementAtOrDefault(1);    // output: 5
int c = array.ElementAtOrDefault(-1);   // output: 0
int d = array.ElementAtOrDefault(1000); // output: 0
```

**See Also**: [DotNetPearls - ElementAt](https://www.dotnetperls.com/elementatordefault)

Answer (score 3):

Make this extension to null check & bound out of range check.

```
public static class ArraySafe
{
    public static bool TryGetElement<T>(this T[] array, int index, out T element)
    {
        if(array == null || index < 0 || index >= array.Length)
        {
            element = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        element = array[index];
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Test()
    {
        int[] intAry = new Int32[10];
        int v;
        if (intAry.TryGetElement(6, out v))
        {
            //here got value
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to loop through the elements in the array safely, just use an enumerator:

```
foreach (int item in theArray) {
   // use the item variable to access the element
}
```

Comment: No, I read command line argument and have to ensure next argument existence without throwing an exception (without loop exit)